# How to edit the text of my Shortcode section within Elementor Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, elementor

I have a section within my Home Page that currently has this:

[image]

That section is being feed by the following Shortcode:

`[27-search-form  layout="wide" align="center" listing_types="for-rent, for-sale" tabs_mode="default" box_shadow="no"]`

What I need is to change the button text from "Search" to "Buscar"

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you please provide your Home page URL?

Comment: www.propiedadespg.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just add a **HTML code block** to your home page then paste this code to it:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).on("ready", function(){
       jQuery(".home .featured-search .search").html("<i class='material-icons'>search</i> Buscar");
   })
</script>
```